# Spring Data JPA: Why findOne(id) executing delete query internally?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have one application where I am using `@ManyToMany` annotation to link two different entities to one parent entity. I am not sure if I have implemented it properly. but when I execute `.findOne()` on parent entity's repository to find it, at first it fetch the data properly but along with that it also executing delete queries internally which delete the record from mapping table (a table which JPA creates itself after adding @ManyToMany annotation.). Following is the generated SQL queries and code snippet:

**Java class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "inventory")
public class Inventory {

    @Id
    Long id;

    // many other properties

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Stream> streams;

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Subject> subjects;
}
```

There is no other annotation I've put in `Stream` and `Subject` entity class to link with `Inventory` class.

When I run my app, it create following tables:

**inventory**
**stream**
**subject**
**inventory_stream**
**inventory_subject**

(inventory_stream and inventory_subject, this two tables are created automatically, I don't know how but I am curious to know and finding out, but no luck so far, please give insight in this context as well).

**Service class**

```
@Transactional
public class InventoryService {

  public Inventory getInventoryById(Integer id) {
      Inventory inv = invRepository.findOne(id);
      if(inv == null) {
            throw new NotFoundException("Entity not found id: "+id);
      }
      return inv;
  }
}
```

**Console log in eclipse**

```
Hibernate: select streams0_.inventory_id as inventor1_1_0_, streams0_.streams_id as streams_2_2_0_, stream1_.id as id1_6_1_, stream1_.stream as stream2_6_1_ from inventory_stream streams0_ inner join stream stream1_ on streams0_.streams_id=stream1_.id where streams0_.inventory_id=?
Hibernate: delete from inventory_stream where inventory_id=?
Hibernate: select subjects0_.inventory_id as inventor1_1_0_, subjects0_.subjects_id as subjects2_3_0_, subject1_.id as id1_7_1_, subject1_.subjectName as subjectN2_7_1_ from inventory_subject subjects0_ inner join subject subject1_ on subjects0_.subjects_id=subject1_.id where subjects0_.inventory_id=?
Hibernate: delete from inventory_subject where inventory_id=?
```

**UPDATE**

removed following properties from applicationContext.xml (entityManagerFactory):

```
<property name="jpaProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</prop>
    </props>
</property>
```

and changed from `FetchType.LAZY` to `FetchType.EAGER`, resolved the issues, but created another issue, that its returning duplicate data in `List<Stream>` and `List<Subject>` when return a single bean of `Inventory`. I don't think that `enable_lazy_load_no_trans` was a root cause of initial issue.

Comment: Can you cross-check once again. I just tried calling findOne on my repository(created many-to-many as you mentioned) and it didn't fire any delete query.

Comment: @Bala, hey I checked again and updated the question.

Comment: @agpt, Did you got any solution about execution of delete query?

Comment: @hrdkisback ah I really don't remember now, but as you can see in the question (Update), I must have followed that way. Beside I do not have any other update as such.

Comment: Ok, thanks for quick response. ;)

Comment: Where else you expect a developer can be :P @hrdkisback